# geArgument return return null after second call in tab layout

Tags: android

In my TabLayout, i tried these tabLayout with only one dynamic fragment. So I used setArguments in getItem Like that.

**RecentSubTabAdapter.java :**

```
public class RecentSubTabAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

    ArrayList<String> myTitleList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Fragment> myFragmentList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();


    public void addFragment(Fragment f, String t)
    {
        myFragmentList.add(f);
        myTitleList.add(t);
    }


    public RecentSubTabAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return myTitleList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("args", myTitleList.get(position));
        myFragmentList.get(position).setArguments(b);
        return myFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return myTitleList.get(position);
    }



    }
```

And I added getArgument in myFragment like that

```
Bundle b = getArguments();
myPosition = b.getString("args").toLowerCase();
```

It was ok for first time calling tab. But when I called multiple tab and re-called first tab. It show NULL POINTER EXCEPTION in getArguments.
PLease Help me

Comment: you cannot use getArguments in your fragments .

Comment: Why? If so what should I use to pass parameter when selecting tab?

Comment: getArguments is no error in first Time.The problem is in second time

Comment: getargument meay be null check for nulll using condition

Comment: I solved the problem by adding offestlimit in myViewPager